# screens of ios extension cannot load icons from react-native-vector-icons

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

Im developing a react native app which consists of an extension where it loads screens same as the main app. When opening the main app every icons from react-native-vector-icons displays as expected while opening extension screens, all icons are replaced with the question mark which means it cannot load icons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out you need to add the icons to info.plist manually.